# Does Netty 4.1 still require setUseClientMode?

Tags: java, netty

The [Netty examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatClientInitializer.java#L47) do not use `sslEngine.setUseClientMode(true|false)`.

However, most code snippets "in the wild" appear to specify `setUseClientMode(...)`.

I understand that the `ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine` will automatically go off the `SslContext`'s mode, so it isn't necessary to specify manually on the `SslEngine` when using OpenSSL as the implementation.

But... the same isn't true for `sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl` AFAIK.

Am I right in saying that we should be specifying `setUseClientMode(...)` if we want our code to be decoupled from the SSL implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not needed as we build the SslContext for client side mode here:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatClient.java#L42